# PowerShell Relation between object values

Tags: object, powershell, match

This might seem like a very stupid question, but I can't seem to figure it out. How can you put a relationship between values of an object?

I think the code will speak for itself:

```
$Collection = ("Fruit","Banana"),("Vegetables","Aubergine"),("Fruit","Appel"),("Vegetables","Courgette") | 
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Type'=$_[0]
            'Content'=$_[1]
        }
    }    
if ($Collection.Type -contains "Fruit" -and $Collection.Content -contains "Courgette") {
    Write-Host "We DID find a match" -ForegroundColor Green
}
else {
    Write-Host "We didn't find a match" -ForegroundColor Red
}

<# Result
Fruit + Banana = "We DID find a match"
Fruit + Courgette= "We DID find a match"
#>
```

How is it possible to only have a match when the pair matches? For example I would like it match in the case of `Fruit + Banana` but not in case of `Fruit + Courgette`.

I'm sorry if this sounds silly.. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `$Collection | ?{$_.Type -eq "Fruit" -and $_.Content -eq "Banana"}   ` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collection a unique value (Content) and a Type that can be repeated. In my solution I am assuming you are never going to have repeated entries like "Fruit/Banana" and "Vegetables/Banana"

Your logical test is: `$Collection.Type -contains "Fruit" -and $Collection.Content -contains "Courgette"`

What is the problem on your logical test? *You are testing **if your collection has "Fruit"** (that is true) **and if your collection has "Courguette"** (that is also true).*

*You have to test **if your collection has "Courgette" and if so, if the type of that "Courguette" object is "Fruit"**...*

You can create a function that looks for the $content and if it exists checks the type. It should return $true on a match.

```
function FindObject($type, $content)
    {
        $index = [array]::IndexOf($Collection.Content,$content)

        if (($index -ge 0) -and ($Collection[$index].Type -eq $type))
        {
            return $true
        }
        else
        {
            return $false
        }

    }
```

**EDIT**: As **@Kayasax** commented you can save code by using
`$Collection | ?{$_.Type -eq "Fruit" -and $_.Content -eq "Banana"}` instead of a function. *Less code lines but harder to read and debug if you want to understand.*

Working example:

```
$Collection = ("Fruit","Banana"),("Vegetables","Aubergine"),("Fruit","Appel"),("Vegetables","Courgette") | 
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Type'=$_[0]
            'Content'=$_[1]
        }
    }    

function FindObject($type, $content)
{
    $index = [array]::IndexOf($Collection.Content,$content)

    if (($index -ge 0) -and ($Collection[$index].Type -eq $type))
    {
        return $true
    }
    else
    {
        return $false
    }

}

#if ( $Collection | ?{$_.Type -eq "Fruit" -and $_.Content -eq "Courgette"} )
if ( (FindObject "Fruit" "Courgette") -eq $true)
{
    Write-Host "We DID find a match" -ForegroundColor Green
}
else 
{
    Write-Host "We didn't find a match" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to create a new custom object, PS already provides key/value collection in a shape of hash table. You can make this much simpler:

```powershell
$h = @{ "Banana" = "Fruit"; "Aubergine" = "Vegetables"; "Appel" = "Fruit" ; "Courgette" = "Vegetables"}
function CheckObject($k, $v){
    if($h.Item($k) -eq $v){
        Write-Host "We DID find a match";
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "We did NOT find a match";
    }
}
```

Result:

```powershell
PS U:\> CheckObject "Banana" "Fruit"
We DID find a match
PS U:\> CheckObject "Banana" "Vegetables"
We did NOT find a match
PS U:\> CheckObject "Courgetee" "Vegetables"
We did NOT find a match
```

The keys(first value) have to be unique, hence flipping from `"Fruit","Banana"`.